# LINQ query to return elements based on two lists and process results based on multiple properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I hope I'll manage to explain my request properly. I have an incoming JSON request that will contain the following data:

```
public class OptimalDateSlotInput
{

    public IEnumerable<LoadareaLocationsDTO> Locations { get; set; }
    public DateTime From { get; set; }
    public DateTime To { get; set; }


    public class LoadareaLocationsDTO
    {
        public string id { get; set; }
        public int bundles { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Given this data I have to return results (time slots) from my DB for a specific time frame (From and To), only for the specific list of locations and only time slots that have remaining capacity >= each of the locations bundles. This is what I have created that returns desired results:

```
    public IEnumerable<PlannedSlot> GetOptimalDateSlots(OptimalDateSlotInput input)
    {
        List<PlannedSlot> returnList = new List<PlannedSlot>();
        var loadAreaList = input.Locations.Select(d => d.id);
        List<int> bundlesList = input.Locations.Select(d => d.bundles).ToList();
        var filterQuery = _context.Slots.Where(d => d.From >= input.From && 
                                                        d.To <= input.To && 
                                                        loadAreaList.Contains(d.LoadArea))
                                                        .ToList();                 

        foreach (var item in filterQuery)
        {
            foreach (var bundle in bundlesList)
            {
                if (item.RemainingCapacity >= bundle)
                    returnList.Add(item);
            }
        }

        return returnList.Distinct();
    }
```

I only manage to do this in two steps and I don't really like the Foreach loops that I am forced to use in order to filter the results based on each Locations bundle property which has to be <= each entries remaining capacity.

Now after I have these results I need to shape them to my needs which are returning only the slots that area available for all `input.Locations.id` at the same time `From`.

I do this in the following way and I'm not sure how precise it is:

```
    public IHttpActionResult GetOptimalDateSlot(OptimalDateSlotInput input)
    {
        var availableSlots = _repo.GetOptimalDateSlots(input);
        var areas = input.Locations.Select(d => d.id);
        var slotsToReturn = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PlannedSlotDto>>(availableSlots);

        var optimalSlots = slotsToReturn.GroupBy(d => d.From).Where(group => group.Count() == areas.Count());

        return Ok(optimalSlots);
    }
```

When I use the `Count()` method I'm trying to make sure that the groups are equal the number of `input.Locations.id` which actually brings the desired results. But there has to be some other way how to return only the slots that are available at the safe time `(From)` for all ids in `input.Locations.id`. I hope I managed to explain the issue correctly.

Comment: You mean "that have remaining capacity >= _any_ of the locations bundles", as your code shows?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace your looping with LINQ to find the possible Date Slots (I changed some variable names to keep it clearer to me):

```
public IEnumerable<PlannedSlot> GetOptimalDateSlots(OptimalDateSlotInput input) {
    var inputLoadAreas = new HashSet<string>(input.Locations.Select(d => d.id));
    var inputBundles = input.Locations.Select(d => d.bundles);
    var possibleSlots = _context.Slots.Where(slot => slot.From >= input.From && slot.To <= input.To &&
                                                  inputLoadAreas.Contains(slot.LoadArea))
                                       .Where(slot => inputBundles.Any(bundle => slot.RemainingCapacity > bundle));
    return possibleSlots;
}
```

Then you can find all the possible dates that have all of the input Load Areas:

```
public IHttpActionResult GetOptimalDateSlot(OptimalDateSlotInput input) {
    var inputAreas = input.Locations.Select(d => d.id).ToList();
    var optimalSlots = GetOptimalDateSlots(input).GroupBy(slot => slot.From)
                                                 .Where(slotg => inputAreas.All(a => slotg.Any(slot => slot.LoadArea == a)));
    var slotsToReturn = Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<PlannedSlotDto>>(optimalSlots);

    return Ok(optimalSlots);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Updated my implementation with good suggestions from your answer. Thanks!